# How to change font color in R?

Tags: r, fonts, colors

How to change the font color in R? Not the label in the graph, the general font color in R. My R 3.3.1 has red text on command lines and blue on the rest...I want to change that.

Comment: Edit -> GUI Preferences -> Console and Pager Colours

Comment: Alternatively, check out the user interface program for R, [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/)

Comment: for the changing color in R. Just check below link   http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/Report/UsingColorInR.pdf

Comment: @PierreLafortune I'm pretty sure that your comment is the only correct answer so far. The OP is clearly not referring to RStudio but to the Windows R-Gui. Also, the question is not addressing the use of colors in pots etc. I suggest that you post your comment as an answer so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using RStudio or any other special IDE software:

Edit -> GUI Preferences -> Console and Pager Colours

On the bottom you will see two menus for changing the colors.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am trying to do! It works!